# Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'error while running Unit test through Espresso

Tags: java, android

I am very new in android development coding. I have developed one very basic app for MO call through pressing one button.

I am trying to test this app through espresso.Here is my code :

**app Name** : Phonecall

**MainActicity.java code** :

```
package com.test.phonecall;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */


        public void onClickFun(View view)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + "xxxxxxxx");
                Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
                startActivity(dial);

            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }

    }
```

**Manifest File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.phonecall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.phonecall.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Test Project :

```
package com.test.phonecall.test;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.Espresso;
import com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.action.ViewActions;
import com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers;
import com.test.phonecall.MainActivity;
import com.test.phonecall.R;

public class TestMainActivity extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    private MainActivity activity;
    private Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public TestMainActivity(String name) {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        this.activity = (MainActivity) super.getActivity();
        this.instrumentation = super.getInstrumentation();
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testPhoneCallBtn() {
        try {           

            Log.d("Test","in testPhoneCallBtn");
            Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.button1)).perform(ViewActions.click());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("MyTestApp", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void testActivityTitleIsCorrect()
    {
        Assert.assertTrue(this.activity.getTitle().equals("PhoneCall"));
        Log.d("Test","in testPhoneCallBtn");
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.button1)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    }
}
```

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.phonecall.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

    <instrumentation
        android:name="com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.test.phonecall"/>

</manifest>
```

Exception Logs :

```
01-12 06:10:35.569: W/dalvikvm(10800): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415d9d58)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800): Process: com.test.phonecall, PID: 10800
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.test.phonecall.test/com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.test.phonecall.test-2.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.phonecall-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test.phonecall.test-2, /data/app-lib/com.test.phonecall-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4379)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5111)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.test.phonecall.test-2.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.phonecall-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test.phonecall.test-2, /data/app-lib/com.test.phonecall-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4376)
01-12 06:10:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(10800):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Please provide exception logs.

Comment: @ Dhrubajyoti Gogoi I have added the logs also can you please help me out in this

Comment: Have you followed the steps mentioned in the [Espresso website](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso). It looks that you have not added them to the classpath.

Comment: @ Dhrubajyoti Gogoi .. As far as i know i have added but can you point me error location .. it would be really help full for me as i am struggling since last one day to figuring out this error but till now no success :(

Comment: How are you running it from eclipse? If yes, go to run configurations and added you jar's to classpath.

Comment: I have checked all the "check Box" apart from Jar one if i will click Jar check box then "Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/test/phonecall/test/BuildConfig;" error is occurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Ensure that the espresso jar is in the libs folder

[image]

2.Ensure that it is exported in the class path

[image]